# Arrays as parameter in enum constructor in java

Tags: java, collections, enums, composite-key

I have 5 data sets of predefined values in double[]:

```
A = {1.5, 1.8, 1.9, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0} 
B = {1.2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.4, 2.9, 3.1} 
.
.
E = {1.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.3, 2.9}
```

how can I represent it in enum?
I am trying to coded it like:

```
private enum Solutions{
 A(double[]),
 B(double[]),
 C(double[]),
 D(double[]),
 E(double[]) ;

 private double[] val;

 private Solutions(double[] pVal){
   this.val = pVal;
 }

}
```

is this possible?

or

what is the best datatype or data structure represent this in java?
in addition to above double[] arrays, user could defined his own customized array.

any suggestion please.

Comment: Enums are compile-time constants, so if you want the user to define his own arrays, an enum is definitely not the way to go. Just use any type of collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rogue's answer is correct and very concise, but for those of us who don't know how to instantiate an array literal as an argument, or your very unfortunate and can't use Java 5+ (I highly doubt this)

You are very close. You just need to instantiate the double array

```
private enum Solutions {
    A(new double[] {1.5, 1.8, 1.9, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0}),
    B(new double[] {1.2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.4, 2.9, 3.1}),
    C(new double[] {}),
    D(new double[] {}),
    E(new double[] {1.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.3, 2.9} ) ;

    private double[] val;

    private Solutions(double[] pVal) {
        this.val = pVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Varargs were intoduced in Java 5

Comment: Oh wow, what an oversight! Thanks for the correction. I've edited the answer. I still feel that my answer is useful for anybody who does not know how to pass an anonymous array as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

I would use varargs for your potential numbers:

```
private Solutions(double... values) {
    this.val = values;
}
```

This would allow you to pass whatever usable values there are:

```
A(12.4, 42.4, 30.2, 1.3),
B(39.2, 230.3, 230.0),
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all answers, they are very useful for me.
so far I worked on this issue and here is a code which can accept customized values for enum.

```
public class X {
    private enum Solutions{
        A (new double [] {1.5, 1.8, 1.9, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0} ),
        B (new double [] {1.2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.4, 2.9, 3.1} ),
        C (new double [] {1.3, 1.7, 0.9, 1.4, 2.2, 3.1} ),
        D (new double [] {1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 2.6, 1.9, 3.1} ),
        E (new double [] {1.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.3, 2.9} ),
        CUSTOM (new double [] {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} );

        private double[] val;

         private Solutions (double[] pVal) {
           val = pVal;
         }

         public double[] getVal(){
             return this.val;
         }

         public void setVal(double[] pVal){
             val = pVal;
         }

    }

    public X() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Solutions a = Solutions.A;
        System.out.println("enum Solution A at index 0 is: " + a.getVal()[0] );

        Solutions custom = Solutions.CUSTOM;
        System.out.println("enum Solution Custom  at index 0 is: " + custom.getVal()[0] );

        double[] custArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
        custom.setVal(custArray);

        System.out.println("enum Solution Custom at index 0 after modification is: " + custom.getVal()[0] );

    }
}
```

now my final question related to this issue is:
is there automated way to force accepting only double[] with length = 6 (specific length array)
or i have to check it by myself?

lets say ... is there any way to write member variable of enum like this:

```
private double[6] val;
```

instead of

```
private double[] val;
```